# How do I detect user navigating back in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a component and I need to detect if user pressed back button in his browser to navigate back.

Currently I'm subscribing router events.

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.routerSubscription = router.events
        .subscribe(event => {

            // if (event.navigatesBack()) ...

        });

}
```

I know that I can use `window.onpopstate` but it feels like a hack when using Angular2.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

---

**EDIT**
Please don't do this.

The official docs say "This class should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use Location." Ref: https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation

---

It's possible to use `PlatformLocation` which has `onPopState` listener.

```
import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common'

(...)

constructor(location: PlatformLocation) {

    location.onPopState(() => {

        console.log('pressed back!');

    });

}

(...)
```

Comment: How to import this in my app.module. Anywhere I put this class I got an error.

Comment: Angular documentation says not to use PlatformLocation directly, use Location instead.

Comment: How do you unsubscribe from this listener?

Comment: @KevinLeStarge you don't. You should use Location instead as suggested by thorin87

Comment: you console.log('pressed back!') but it will be triggered by the forward button as well

Comment: Actually all we know that we navigated to another state within the history.

Answer (score 44):

IMO better method of listenting for popstate events is to subscribe to location service

```
import {Location} from "@angular/common";

constructor(private location: Location) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.location.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

It doesn't use PlatformLocation directly (as documentation suggest) and you can unsubscribe any time you want.

Comment: Don't forget to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy() !

Comment: As an alternative you could subscribe to route.params.subscribe(...); Difference is that it will already fire when you initial enter the page, which location.subscribe(...) doesn't. The latter only fires when the parameter actually has changed.

Comment: @Humppakäräjät how does that help to tell if user navigated back or not? There is no access to the history api in route..

Comment: @Mackelito yes you are right it won't directly detect if he went back or forth. It only fires when it has detected that the route parameters have changed, which might happen when the user hits the browsers back or forth button.

Comment: But wont that happen on any navigation?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would detect if the previous page had the exact same url. But what would you change then, anyways ;)

Comment: @Humppakäräjät *It only fires when it has detected that the route parameters have changed, which might happen when the user hits the browsers back or forth button.* - so as it only **might work** it is useless.

Comment: It doesnot provide a solution for user navigating back

Answer (score 25):

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
```

and then listen for `popstate` on the `window` object:

```
  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event) {
    console.log('Back button pressed');
  }
```

This code works for me on latest Angular 2.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. No event is being triggered when the back button is clicked in this case.

Comment: It's working fine on ng-version="5.2.9". It is simply awesome!

Comment: how do you determine if it is triggered by a **back** or **forward** ?

Answer (score 4):

As thorin87 answer dont use PlatformLocation. We need subscribe an unsubscribe.

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';    

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = <Subscription>this
    .location
    .subscribe(() => x => console.log(x));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in angular 8+

```
constructor(private readonly route: Router) {
this.route.events
  .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart))
  .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
    if (event.restoredState) {
      this.isBackUrl = true;
    }
  });
```

}

Comment: This doesn't check whether the navigation was back or forward.

Answer (score -2):

This solution works for all versions of Angular.

```
import { PlatformLocation } from'@angular/common';

constructor( private _location: PlatformLocation ) {

this._location.onPopState (() => {
 `enter code here` // You could write code to display a custom pop-up here.

 // window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'; //Navigate to another location when the browser back is clicked.


});
```

Comment: Official docs say "This class should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use Location." Ref: https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation