# How to add a confirmation box on the click of browser back/forward button with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular2 application, I want to add a confirmation box on click of browser back/forward button. How can I do it in typescript?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect user navigating back in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381814/how-do-i-detect-user-navigating-back-in-angular2)

Comment: bipin patel, I checked this solution but it is not fulfilling my requirements as it is not described there, how to add a pop-up and how to prevent action on click of cancel in the pop-up.

Comment: @Deepak make an attempt yourself, and come back in case of an actual problem with your code :)