# How do I close the bootstrapModal on click of browser's back button in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

Using the following code to display bootstrap modal, but when user clicks browser back button, the modal background stays. How can I close the modal and background gracefully? Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="bootstrapModal" #bootstrapModal  class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"  aria-hidden="true"  role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: #232323">
      <!-- model body section -->
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to listen to browser back navigation event. There are multiple ways to do that (check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381814/how-do-i-detect-user-navigating-back-in-angular2) for details). Here I choosed to use [Angular Location service](https://angular.io/api/common/Location).
Then, when this event is triggered, you have to programmatically close the modal. This can be done using [Bootstrap Modal API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), calling `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`.

Based on your code snippet, I assume that you are using bootstrap by including it traditionnaly (not using existing Angular integration like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)).
Here is a [simple Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sasensi-bootstrap-modal) demonstrating a working solution.
First click on the button to open the modal, then click on browser back button and see that modal is automatically closed.

#### Component

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from "@angular/common";

declare const $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('modal') modal: ElementRef;

  constructor(private location: Location) {
    // simulate a navigation history adding consecutive hashs
    window.location.hash = 'hash1';
    window.location.hash = 'hash2';
    window.location.hash = 'hash3';

    // when location change...
    this.location.subscribe(location => {
      // ...close popup
      $(this.modal.nativeElement).modal('hide');
    });
  }
}
```

#### Template

```
<!-- Modal trigger button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Click me to open modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div #modal class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Now click on browser previous or next button to see modal closing.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```