# Hide Angular Material Sidenav with Android Back button

Tags: angular, angular-material, back-button, mat-sidenav

Is it possible to hide an Angular Material Sidenav component by using Android 'Back' button when you open your site with an Android device?

Comment: Your question is very specific to Android - you may want to add an android tag to your post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381814/how-do-i-detect-user-navigating-back-in-angular2

Comment: @Eliseo none of the solutions worked for me !