# How to Go back to particular page by clearing routing history, using Angular Router/Location

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Going back to the HOME Page by clearing the routing history is my requirement

I have tried with below code. But all codes shown below didn't met my requirement.

```
this.router.navigate(['/services/paymentProcessing'], { skipLocationChange: true });

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    window.history.go(-4);
    this.location.back();
    this.router.navigate(['/services/#SH']);
  }
```

I need to go back to Home Page/particular page from my specific page by clearing the routing history. Can anyone let me know the solution

Comment: have you tried `this.router.navigate(["/C"], { replaceUrl: true });`

Comment: Your answer works. But it will not clear the history. I also need to clear my history. So that after going to Home Page,url back button should disable.

Comment: Finally, I didn't able to clear my history. But known to stay on current page, after going to particular page(using above line of code).

Answer (score 1):

By referring to the answers at [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser) and [How do I detect user navigating back in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381814/how-do-i-detect-user-navigating-back-in-angular2), I wish to let you know the solution for above task.

For going back to particular page, by skipping current page you can use the code

```
this.router.navigate(["/C"], { replaceUrl: true });
```

as said by Mr. Stark Buttowski

And then if you wish to stay on current page(in my case HomePage) without clearing the history,

```
import { Location } from "@angular/common";

constructor(public location: Location){}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.location.subscribe(
      x=> history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname)
    );
  }
```

so that you can block back button navigation.

If there are, any better lines of code, looking forward..

Looking for the answer, which is better than above